# built in methods for Django CBV's

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I am learning Django out of pure passion and I seem to have trouble understanding some core principles of Django that really give me headackes and i tried searching online and reading the docs but i don't seem to fully understand. I'll just simply shoot the questions and try to be clear . I apologise for anything stupid I say . I am just trying to get my knowledge straight.

**1. What is a "request"?**

OK, so I am thinking of a GET request for a webpage but online i see python code like `self.request.user.is_superuser` and i am thinking of an User object fetched and displayed to the template to which i can apply User methods. It is clearly more to this request than i already know.

**2. CBV's built in methods. The get methods. How do they execute? In what order.**

I noticed programmers override these methods sometime . If i redefine more than one method in a CBV i start getting weird behaviour.

For example if i declare and redefine 2 methods in a Detail View `get_object()` and `get_queryset()` which of them will be executed first after calling the view? Being a method it should be called somehow in order to execute but i don't know the order how  these methods are called for a CBV if there is more than one. Probably i should only define one of them, not both.

**3. Queryset. Is it a list?**

I have an ideea  what querysets are and that you can apply filters to them but what do they return? Do they return objects of the model i am querying?.

OK so, if i have a DetailView CBV and override the get_queryset() method will this return on object and pass it to my template?. Here I am using a filter but what if am not using a filter. What will the CBV return? Will it return the entire set of objects?

```
class UserDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin,DetailView):
    context_object_name='user_detail'
    model=models.User
    template_name='basicapp/user_detail.html' 
    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        qs = super().get_queryset(*args, **kwargs)
        if not self.request.user.is_superuser:
            qs = qs.filter(pk=self.request.user.pk)
        return qs
```

**4. Can you kindly recommend a Udemy course, video course or book where querysets, CBV methods and ORM are explained clearly?**

Preferably video cause it makes so much difference when i see the code working

The thing is I understood how the MVT mechanism works but these class built in methods and overriding them gives me a lot of problems . I never encountered them before and when i start using them  I feel like as if  i am walking in the dark .

Sorry for the long post.
Thanks

Answer (score 3):

> 1. What is a `request`?

It is a [**`HttpRequest`** object [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest). This is an object that contains data about the request the client made to the server. For example this contains an attribute [**`.method`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpRequest.method) that contains a string like `'GET'`, `'POST'`, `'PATCH'`, etc. that specifies the request method used.

> but online i see python code like `self.request.user.is_superuser` and I am thinking of an `User` object fetched and displayed to the template to which I can apply User methods.

One can install [*middleware* [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/middleware/), this is tooling that pre-processes the request, or post-processes the response. Normally the [**`AuthenticationMiddleware`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/middleware/#django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware) is added in the `settings.py` file by default. This will add an extra attribute `.user` to the request that lazily loads the user that has been logged in. If you would remove this middleware, the `.user` attribute will no longer exist.

> 2. CBV's built in methods. The get methods. How do they execute? In what order.

That depends on the specific class-based view. The documentation however specifies how most methods are performed. For example for a [**`ListView`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/class-based-views/generic-display/#listview), the documentation mentions the *method flowchart*:

> Method Flowchart
>
> 1. `setup()`
> 2. `dispatch()`
> 3. `http_method_not_allowed()`
> 4. `get_template_names()`
> 5. `get_queryset()`
> 6. `get_context_object_name()`
> 7. `get_context_data()`
> 8. `get()`
> 9. `render_to_response()`

It also links to the methods that explain what these are doing.

In essence, each class-based view can have methods like `get`, `post`, `put`, `patch`, etc. Based on the *method* of the request, the request is dispatched to the method with the same name.

> 3. Queryset. Is it a list?

**No**. A `QuerySet` is an object that more or less represents a *query* that you can perform on the database. QuerySets are *lazy*. That means that as long as you do not iterate over them or for example call `len(…)` over these, they will *not* make that query. If you iterate, etc. over these, they will make a query to the database, and then you iterate over the result of the query. The results are normally wrapped in model objects (unless you use functions like [**`values(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values) or [**`values_list(…)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list).

> 4. Can you kindly recommend a Udemy course, video course or book where querysets, CBV methods and ORM are explained clearly?

It might help to start with the [Django tutorials](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/intro/tutorial01/). These go step-by-step over the architecture of Django. The [documentation on the QuerySet API](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/) explains how you can make querysets. The [page on *Query expressions*](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/expressions/) gives examples on how to make more advanced queries. Finally the Django documentation also has a [page on class-based views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/class-based-views/).

Comment: Thank you for the answers and refferences. 